# how to avoid pass raw message everywhere when use Akka to build a program?

Tags: erlang, akka

I'm using Akka to build my runtime message system. But it often suffers the awkward situation: many messages are sent with `!` and it's difficult to trace the business logic.
From the book of `Programming in Erlang`, it is not recommended to expose a message to others but encapsulate the actor message with a function and export it with `export([func1/1])` or something else.

So, is it possible to use function call pattern in Akka?
How do you read code with so many messages when use Akka to build a large system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new experimental Akka typed support goes a long way to helping understand and trace business logic:

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/typed.html

What this does is allow you to encode the protocols to speak to actors in the type system, which can make it a lot easier to understand how your system works when you read the code.

Another option is to use Cinnamon (a Lightbend commercial library) to trace messages, which can you give an understanding of the flow of control at runtime. Here's a blog post about it:

https://developer.lightbend.com/blog/2017-05-08-cinnamon-2-4-with-opentracing-integration/

If you're doing a lot of asks on your actors, a common pattern is to put that behind methods that return futures. For example:

```
class MyService(actor: ActorRef) {
  def doSomething(msg: Something): Future[Result] = {
    (actor ? msg).mapTo[Result]
  }
}
```

Of course you can apply the same thing to regular tells, except that your return type is going to be `Unit`.

Finally, a common pattern in Akka is to put all the message classes in the companion object of the actor:

```
object MyActor {
  /** This message does something */
  case class MessageOne(foo: String)
  /** This message does something else */
  case class MessageTwo(bar: String)
}
class MyActor extends Actor {
  import MyActor._
  override def receive = {
    case MessageOne(foo) =>
      ...
    case MessageTwo(bar) =>
      ...
   }
 }
```

While perhaps this doesn't help with following business logic, it does make it easier for someone new to the system to get an idea of how to speak to an actor by putting all the messages (with documentation) in one place.

Also a word on structuring your code - actors are supposed to have a limited responsibility with a well defined protocol. A well designed Akka based system won't require you to understand the entire flow of messages everywhere at once, it should be straight forward to reason about each actor individually. Careful use of actor hierarchies to extract child processes as child actors can really help here. To put another way, if in order to understand how your system is behaving, you need to understand how thousands of messages between hundreds of actors are flowing, then you definitely have a design problem, and need to rethink how you can break your actors up to into isolated units that can be easily put together like building blocks.

Comment: *Surely* there is some better system than this. I mean, its Akka. Erlang has been around forever and... seriously?

Comment: Great advice! A little thinking about put mesaage in a object maybe not always pretty workaround. Such as, if I have a case class message want used at two or more actor defines.Besides, I think typed actor has its limit because we can't promise all message received is well typed,its belong to what the actor does.

Answer (score 0):

You could do same thing Erlang does and hide all your message passing behind functions. Or in other words, rather than dealing with actors, you should deal with general (domain abstraction) classes, and use actors only as underling implementation.

```
case class Cat(name: String)


trait Shelter {
  def leave(cat: Cat): Unit
}


class ActorShelter extends Shelter with Actor {

  var cats = List[Cat]()

  def leave(cat: Cat) =
    this.self ! cat

  def receive = {
    case cat: Cat =>
      cats = cat :: cats
  }
}
```

This would allow you to use `Shelter` in your code without ever knowing that it is an actor.

Of course you still need to decide if you will return `Unit` on all casts with `!`, or maybe just reference to yourself. And if you will return `Future` on calls with `?`, or will you wait for actual value.

Comment: straight but effective

Comment: But a problem is when I create a `ActorShelter` I only get a `ActorRef` type. How can I get `Shelter `?

Comment: That is a very good point, and slightly more complicated. In Erlang you just can spawn a new process/actor, in Akka you have to do it in some context (system or other already existing actor). And it can vary depending on how you structure your application, so there is no one-fits-them-all solution. I will try to investigate it little more and maybe update my answer.

Comment: thanks for you could take some time to the problem. Looking forward to your newest investigation.